# Does the child Oracle curse grant eternal youth

Tags: pathfinder-1e, curses, aging, oracle

So there’s the third party oracle curse called child which reads as follows. Putting aside the large number of design flaws. **as it is written** could it be interpreted as having eternal youth or would it just prevent you from aging until you reach the age where you would have died due to old age.

> Child [3PP] Source Oracle’s Curse, copyright 2014 by RJ Grady,
> published by Tripod Machine.
>
> You became an oracle early in life, and your body has remained that of a child.
>
> EFFECT You take a -4 penalty
> to your Strength modifier for the purpose of Strength checks and your
> maneuver bonus, and gain a +2 bonus to Escape Artist and Stealth
> checks. Your age cannot be magically altered. NPCs may become friendly
> or unfriendly ( GM’s choice) depending on your behavior and the
> situation. Non-magical armor must be tailor-made for your, otherwise
> it can only be donned hastily, if it can be worn at all.
>
> At 5th level, your Strength penalty is reduced to -2.
>
> At 10th level, you gain a bonus revelation.
>
> At 15 level, add either holy aura or unholy aura (your choice) to your spells known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No.

The [Child Oracle Curse](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Oracle/oracle-curses/#Child_3PP) states:

> You became an oracle early in life, and **your body has remained that of a child**.
>
> EFFECT
>
> You take a -4 penalty to your Strength modifier for the purpose of Strength checks and your maneuver bonus, and gain a +2 bonus to Escape Artist and Stealth checks. **Your age cannot be magically altered**. NPCs may become friendly or unfriendly ( GM’s choice) depending on your behavior and the situation. Non-magical armor must be tailor-made for your, otherwise it can only be donned hastily, if it can be worn at all.

Emphasis mine. The curse prevents you from being magically aged, but it does nothing to stop normal aging. Instead, it seems that you'll always look like a child until you die, as nothing prevents you from dying of old age, just from looking like you have an old age.

Comment: Does that mean things like the aging table would still apply?

Comment: @MageintheBarrel I would say so. Otoh, I could see a GM saying no.